# How can I allow remote login (out of office IP ) to some users only in redmine application?

Tags: redmine

Is there a way we can allow a group of users to access redmine from any IP, whereas other users to login from a set of IP only

Answer (score 0):

Currently (Redmine 4.1),  there is no such feature, however it's an open-source software, and you are welcomed to either request such feature on [their tracker](https://redmine.org/issues) or develop your own code. So if you quickly need solution, there are few options:

**Method 1:**
You can solve the problem by having remote users connect via VPN which will make them have IP from given set of IP's.

**Method 2:**
Develop special authentication plugin which would give you ability to choose from which IP's user can login.

**Method 3:**
Modify Redmine's core files and database or create custom field which holds user's approved IP address or range by modifying /mode/user.rb file

So you should add something like:

```
return nil unless IPAddr.new(user.permitted_ip).include? request.env['HTTP_X_REAL_IP'] || request.env['REMOTE_ADDR']
```

after

```
 # Returns the user that matches provided login and password, or nil
  def self.try_to_login(login, password, active_only=true)
    login = login.to_s.strip
    password = password.to_s

    # Make sure no one can sign in with an empty login or password
    return nil if login.empty? || password.empty?
    user = find_by_login(login)
    if user
    # user is already in local database
      return nil unless user.check_password?(password)
      return nil if !user.active? && active_only
```

(Above code should work if you are not using external auth source)